# Rails: getting errors for "no route matches" on paths I don't link to anywhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My logs are showing that I'm getting quite a few errors for random paths that I don't even link to anywhere on my site. What does this mean? A few examples:

> no route matches /apple-touch-icon.png
>
> No route matches [GET] "/rss"
>
> No route matches [GET] "/support/wp-login.php"
>
> No route matches [GET] "/blog/wp-login.php"
>
> No route matches [GET] "/phpmyadmin"

I'm not using a wordpress site, so why would I be getting these errors?

Comment: on production server?

Comment: Is there a good way to block these route errors?

Answer (score 1):

**A try to hack.**

If your server hasn't responded to any of those requests its well and good,
if you cross verify the ip addresses of those requests on google, you will pretty much find the information in and abouts.

I had similar requests for rails app, but there was nothing to worry about.

It must be automated to check if any valid responses triggered from your server.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I also noticed I was getting a lot of visits to /ahoy/visits.. Do you think that's a hack as well? How can I tell if it's a real error or just a bot hitting every endpoint?

Comment: The /rss request semms harmless enough.